# Is the gradient operator surjective?

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be open and bounded with Lipschitz
boundary. Is the gradient operator $\nabla :H^{1} ( \Omega ) \rightarrow L^{2}
( \Omega )$ surjective? Here $H^{1} ( \Omega ) =W^{1,2} ( \Omega )$ the
Sobolev space of real valued functions in $L^{2}$ with weak derivative in $L^{2}$.

For unbounded sets in $\mathbb{R}$ the answer is clearly no, since any
compactly supported continuous function is in $L^{2} ( \mathbb{R} )$ but has
non integrable primitive.

So, if I try to disprove this for bounded sets, my usual simple test for these
things, the set $( 0,1 ) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and the function $x^{\alpha}$,
which is in $L^{p}$ iff $\alpha >-n/p$ doesn't really help much as a
candidate. Integrating is always possible and yields a function in $H^{1} (
\Omega )$.

Ideas? Solution anyone? What about vector valued functions?

Comment: If $\nabla u = f$, then $\operatorname{curl} f =0$, already in a classical sense. And weak derivatives coincide with classical derivatives, provided these exist.

Comment: Wow, that was easy... :( Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)^n$ denote the set of $C^\infty$, compact supported vector fields defined in $\Omega$. Define $$\mathcal{V}=\{\varphi\in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)^n:\ \operatorname{div}\varphi=0 \}$$

Denote by $H$ the closure of $\mathcal{V}$ in $L^2(\Omega)^n$. It can be showed that $$H=\{u\in L^2(\Omega)^n:\ \operatorname{div} u=0,\ \gamma(u)=0\}$$

$$H^{\perp}=\{u\in L^2(\Omega)^n:\ \exists\ p\in H^1(\Omega),\ u=\nabla p\}$$

where $\gamma$ is defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396288/gaussostrogradsky-formula-for-distributions) and $H^{\perp}$ is the orthogonal of $H$ in $L^2(\Omega)^n$. Therefore $$L^2(\Omega)^n=H\oplus H^\perp$$

For references take a look in this [book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-5975-0) of Boyer and Fabrie, in section 3.3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome. Note also the comment of @Siminote. It is really useful.